# Windows Jenkins Slave and ssh-agent

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, apr

I have a master (Ubuntu) and a slave (Mac) and build is working fine. Now, I need to add a Windows 7 slave. The problem is that I use the ssh-agent plugin and it requires special tomcat-related installation:
http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/

In particular, it is required to build/install APR. My problem is that I cannot open the solution file because it seems outdated. Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to run Jenkins slave on Windows through Java Web Start (the easy way for me on Windows).
You can take a look on my [blog](http://mobiledevtest.blogspot.co.il/2014/01/jenkins-slave-on-mac-or-windows-8.html) from more details.
Just download the jnlp into your windows slave and run the following command:

```
*java.exe -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl file:///<path to downloaded file>/slave-agent.jnlp -noCertificateCheck*
```

Comment: The issue was more about ssh keys that need to be forwarded to the slaves to avoid command prompt each time git fetch is executed on the slaves. My solution was to store ssh keys on slaves without passphrase and use your method to launch the slaves. Thanks.